# Enumerate binary square matrices up to symmetry, with given property on contiguous 2 by 2 submatrices

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find a set $\mathcal M_n$ of all matrices $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that:

1. Every contiguous $2\times 2$ submatrix of $M$ has at least one $0$.
2. Replacing any $0$ with $1$ in $M$ breaks the first property.

Additionally, set $\mathcal M_n$ does not contain symmetric duplicates.

By symmetric, I mean the [symmetry group of the square](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dihedral_Group_D4#Example_of_Dihedral_Group).

(Rotations, reflections about axes and main diagonals.)

> Can we efficiently generate all such matrices for given $n$?

---

If I'm not mistaken, when $n=1,2,3,4,\dots$ then $|\mathcal M_n|=0,1,5,17,\dots$

When $n=2$, we have $1$ element in the set:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

When $n=3$, we have $5$ elements in the set:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &0 \\
1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 &0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &0 \\
1 &1 &1 \\
1 &0 &1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &1 \\
1 &1 &0 \\
1 &0 &1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &1 \\
1 &0 &1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &1 \\
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

When $n=4$, we have $17$ elements in the set:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

> Can there exist a formula for the number of such matrices?